# How to get location without GPS in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I want to get my device location with internet or wifi. not use gps. How ı do this?

Comment: Do you want to avoid using GPS on a device that has GPS, or do you want to find the location of a device that does not have GPS? The two are different seeing as the location services should help you with the second, but you are going to have to create your own location services (or use a 3rd party one) for the first.

Comment: Specifically what I want is to use only location service provided by IP based and GSM, no matter device has GPS. In the long term, I am planning to use this service for all Windows Phone devices supporting or unsupporting GPS.

Comment: So even if the device *could* use GPS (because it has the hardware), you want to *avoid* using it (maybe to avoid the Location security prompt?). If so, you should use a reverse-IP lookup service

Answer (score 2):

By default, the phone will use the best available position method, falling back to GSM if need be.

The GeoLocator class has a DesiredAccuracy property, which allows you to upgrade this as well

```
geolocator.desiredAccuracy = Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionAccuracy.High;
```